# Can You Use Bootstrap Without Using Its Grid System?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to use *just* the Bootstrap components / JS (buttons, popovers, etc.,) while not using the grid system for layout? Or does that not work because the component styles / layout is somehow tied to the grid system classes?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to ignore it? It is pretty useful.

Comment: I just made a blog without using the grid but using a lot of the other stuff. It's easier to do with LESS, just comment out the import of various files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ignore the grid system if you want. Everything will still work just fine.

Comment: this is true but its not a solution what the op is asking for.

Comment: @Dude How is it not? He asked if he could not use the grid system. I said yes, you can. Seems pretty clear to me...

Answer (score 4):

sure, you can also customize the components for your needs on their website to avoid redundant components:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/